# How to remove top space of `Form` in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui

How do I top align a `Form` within a `NavigationView`.  I have the below, when I remove `NaviagationView` from the body, the `Form` is top aligned.  With `NavigationView` in place, I get spacing in between(red box added to show space).  I can use `.padding(.top, -20)` on the Form but while this works it skews things slightly.

[image: Screenshot]

```
NavigationView {
    Form {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Name:").underline().font(.headline)
                TextField("Name", text: $routine.name)
                
            }
            roundPicker()
            TimeSelectionView(stateName: "A", stateDuration: "0:30", stateBackground: "#df405a")
            TimeSelectionView(stateName: "B", stateDuration: "1:30", stateBackground: "#4ea1d3")
            TimeSelectionView(stateName: "C", stateDuration: "3:00", stateBackground: "#4f953b")
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Create", displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing:
        Button(action: {
            //Save Routine
            self.routine.rounds = self.roundsArray[self.rounds]
            
            print("Workout Name: \(self.routine.name)")
            print("Workout Rounds: \(self.routine.rounds)")
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: The gap also appears when applying `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` to a `List` view and the accepted answer also works in that case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

SwiftUI `Form` is actually a grouped style `UITableView` under the hood and that is default `tableHeaderView`. So you can remove it like this:

#### iOS 13

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() { // this can be done in `onAppear` modifier if you need to restore the appereance later on `onDisappear`
        UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ,,,
    }
}
```

## iOS 14

Apple is limiting the `appearance` hack and setting the `tableHeaderView`'s frame is one of them so we need to dig more around by adding these steps:

#### 1. Use constraint instead of `frame`:

```
init() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
    UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = view
}
```

#### 2. Force reload the table:

The constraint is added but it needs a reload. SwiftUI does not allow you to reload a list manually. So we need to add a dummy view and a dummy `state` to trick it:

```
@State var loaded = false // need for stay update
,,,

    List {

        if loaded {
            Text("Actual content of the list")

        } else {
            Text("Dummy content. Not important")
                .onAppear {
                    loaded = true // need for instatnt force update 
                }
        }

    }
```

---

#### Note1:

Try never hard-code any numbers (like -35 for inset!). Numbers vary on different devices and platforms and states and etc.

#### Note2:

`.zero` frame is not working. You should pass at least a minimum height if you use `frame` for iOS 13 or `UIKit`.

#### Note3:

All methods are **hacks** and Apple is trying to restrict access to underlying types like `UITableView`. So stay up to date and try to help the community.

#### Note4:

Contribute to the community by upvoting and commenting. So people will be more motivated to dig in unknown places and bring us cool stuff.

#### Note5:

Since we are using the Appearance proxy, any change will be applied to all `TableView`s in the app. You can store the state of the original `Appearance` -> apply the new style `onAppear` and restore the original `onDisaper` if needed.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly it!

Comment: Is there any way to not necessarily do this application-wide, but only for the Form?

Comment: Yes. Doing it onAppear()

Comment: This also works for List with SidebarStyle() on iPad. Even works in Xcode12 for List, didn't try Form.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini long time ago now, I know, but your suggestion still makes it global, just from the point on when this code was first executed onAppear.

Comment: @jeanmartin thanx for reminding that. I have added that as a note and also iOS 14 method :) Thanks for your support

Answer (score 14):

Setting the table header view is no longer working for me in Xcode 12. Instead, setting a negative top content inset seems to achieve the same thing.

```
UITableView.appearance().contentInset.top = -35
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Xcode 12.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

if you use [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) add this to your NavigationView

```
.introspectTableView {
    $0.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

```swift
Form {
   // ...
}._safeAreaInsets(EdgeInsets(top: -18, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
```

It also works for `List`. But sometimes it can affect a large navigation bar title where it appears inline as if you scrolled.

Answer (score -3):

Cleaner add a navbartitle to form section and then set hidden

```
Form {
// add end of form section
}.navigationBarHidden(true).navigationBarTitle("Title") // Form
```

Comment: This removes the navigationbar, not the space above the first Form elements.