# Remove top padding from List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've seen similar questions like this one here on Stack Overflow, but none of them have been able to answer my question.

I have created a `List`, but I want to remove the padding space (marked with a red arrow) above the content in the `List`. How can I remove it when using a `GroupedListStyle`?

[image: Screenshot]

This is a `List` within a `VStack` within a `NavigationView` that is displayed via `fullscreenCover`:

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    VStack {
      taskEventPicker
      myList
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Add Task", displayMode: .inline)
  }
}
```

where `taskEventPicker` is a segmented `Picker` (boxed in green):

```swift
var taskEventPicker: some View {
  Picker("Mode", selection: $selection) { /* ... */ }
  .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
  .padding()
}
```

and `myList` is the form in question (boxed in yellow):

```swift
var myList: some View {
  List { /* ... */ }
  .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
}
```

**What I've Tried**

- [Removing the header of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62881662/12101201)
- [Hiding the Navigation Bar title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62882003/12101201)
- [Setting `UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView` to an empty frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683887/12101201)
- [Attempting `UITableView.appearance().contentInset.top = -35`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63607411/12101201)
- [Setting `listRowInsets`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58192802/12101201) (this affects all list rows)

Note: I'm looking for an answer that can apply to the `GroupedListStyle`. I understand that this issue does not occur with `PlainListStyle`. This padding issue also occurs with the default `listStyle`.

Xcode version: 12.5

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Firstly, I would say that `GroupedListStyle` is working as intended.

> On iOS, the grouped list style displays a larger header and footer
> than the plain style, which visually distances the members of
> different sections.

You say you have tried this, but it does work for me (Xcode 12.5.1):

```
    List { ... }    
    .onAppear(perform: {
        UITableView.appearance().contentInset.top = -35
    })
```

You could also hide the list header, by using a `ZStack` with the List at the bottom of the stack and the `Picker` over the top.  The Picker does have transparency, so you would also have to add an opaque view to act as background for the `Picker`.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            List { ... }
            .listStyle(.grouped)
            .padding(.top, 30)
            
            Color.white
                .frame(height: 65)
            
            Picker { ... }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Add Task", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

[image]

As far as I can see this just appears the same as `PlainListStyle` would do, but I assume you have a particular reason for wanting to use `GroupedListStyle`.

Comment: A wonderful solution! Thank you @rbaldwin! I did not even think to use a `ZStack` with the picker.

Comment: For anybody getting here who, unlike the OP, does NOT need the `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` and has no style specified in their code, adding an explicit `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` can be an effective solution to getting rid of the undesired space at the top of their list.  (This is NOT "answering in a comment," because this approach does NOT solve the OP's question, which requires keeping the GroupedListStyle.)

Comment: This didn't work for me in Xcode 13 and iOS 15.5

Comment: It works for me: `List {...}.padding(.top, -20)` without `ZStack` and so on...

Comment: On current iOS versions you must use `UICollectionView.appearance().contentInset.top = -35` because `List` is now a `UICollectionView` underneath

Answer (score 6):

Give a header to the first section in your list: `Section(header: Spacer(minLength: 0))`

Disclaimer: this doesn't totally remove the top spacing, but it does yield the same result as the native Settings app.

Note: This worked for me on iOS 14.5

```
VStack {
    List {
        Section(header: Spacer(minLength: 0)) {
            Text(verbatim: "First Section")
        }

        Section {
            Text(verbatim: "Second Section")
        }
    }
    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
}
```

[image: Without Section Header] [image: With Section Header] [image: Native Settings App]

Comment: Best answer, and no hacking with UITableView

Comment: iOS16 this no longer works

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar setup where I had some views and a List in a VStack and I had an undesired space that appeared on the top of my List.  In my case I needed to set the VStack spacing to 0 and that solved the issue because it was actually just spacing from the VStack.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) { ... }
```

Comment: I thought I've already checked all Stacks, but apparently I found a LazyVStack in the middle of the UI structure (seemed to be quite unrelated to my problem). After I set a 0 spacing to my LazyVStack, the problem disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `contentInsent` part of the accepted answer works perfectly fine unless for instance as in my case, at the end of a navigation stack you want to use it in some detail view containing a `List` with `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` set to `.inline`. When navigating back in the stack to a view using another `List` with `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` set to `.large`, the `List` content and `NavigationBar` interlace awfully. And they probably might as well do whatever the `navigationBarTitleDisplayMode` is set to.

Switching to `listStyle(.plain)` in my case isn't a feasable option, because then in the detail view, I loose the beautifully animated built-in transitions to and from List's `EditMode`, that seem to exist only in the grouped `listStyle` varieties.

Finally, after quite a few days of frustration I figured out that `tableHeaderView` is the approach that works best for my problem - and of course, it works just as well to solve the original question. It's all in here ...:

[XCode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview)

... and in this sentence:

"When assigning a view to this property [i.e. `tableHeaderView`], set the height of that view to a nonzero value"

So I do like:

```
List {
  // bla bla bla
}
.listStyle(.grouped)
.onAppear {
  let tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
  tableHeaderView.frame.size.height = 1
  UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
}
```

It's as simple as that. Hope it might help you, too!

Comment: @Niels this is no longer working with iOS 16 since the List is no longer implemented based on UITableView, do you have a work-around?

Comment: Hello Claudiu, I'm very sorry for answering so late. I must admit I was stupid enough not to expect any questions. I promise to be more attentive in the future. 

It is true it's not working anymore, but with iOS 16 I found myself very happy with the plain list's style animation to and from editMode. That's why I didn't look for any other workaround and decided to configure my list in the plain list style.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to add

`List { ... }.offset(x: 0, y: -30).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)`

to the List. Since you won't be able to scroll all the way up when using this add a `Spacer(minLength: 30)` at the very bottom of the List.

Answer (score 1):

Add top padding for List and Spacer with minLength 0 for first Section Header

```
NavigationView {
    List { 
       Section {
         Text("My Header")
       } header: {
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
    }
    .listStyle(.grouped)
    .padding(.top, -20)
}
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible solution

```
List {...}
.onAppear {
   UICollectionView.appearance().contentInset.top = -20
}
```

you can use this modifier in the list

Answer (score 0):

You specifically mention it is not an option for you to use `PlainListStyle`, which is understandable. However, are you simply looking for an alternative to `PlainListStyle` that does not have the padded sides? If so, I'd recommend trying `InsetListStyle`.

The fat header is a core feature of `GroupedListStyle`. Generally if I have to hack my way out of a core feature of anything, it's a red flag. I think we'd have to know more about why `GroupedListStyle` feels like the only option for you, but my gut feeling here is there is an easier, more out-of-the-box way, and it may be `InsetListStyle`.

Answer (score -1):

my 2 cents. I arrived here for the same reason.

take a look at:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662544

it' seems the correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
extension View {
    /// Clear tableview and cell color
    func tableClearColor() {
        let tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableHeaderView.frame.size.height = 0.5
        UITableView.appearance().tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
    }
}
```